Git no rastrea carpeta lang en laravel 11
estoy empezando un proyecto de laravel 11 y descargue un paquete de validacion en español para los formularios y funciona todo bien, pero cuando queria hacer el commit me di cuenta que la carpeta no esta siento rastreada por git, ya revise el gitignore pero no esta siendo ignorada, incluso le puse la regla !lang/ para validar que la deja agregar pero tampoco me aparece en git
les dejo el gitignore para ver a lo mejor algo estoy omitiendo
!lang/*
/.phpunit.cache
/node_modules
/public/build
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/storage/pail
/vendor
.env
.env.backup
.env.production
.phpactor.json
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
auth.json
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
/.fleet
/.idea
/.nova
/.vscode
/.zed



Si desesas versionar la carpeta lang/, entonces no debes definirla en el archivo gitignore, elimina esta linea del archivo:
lang/

Si deseas que tu carpeta lang/ sea versionada, es necesario que contenga archivos, yo creo que ese serìa el verdadero problema

Ya lo resolvi, resulta que el hice el git clone dentro de la carpeta lang del proyecto laravel y me esta dando error porque tengo un reporsitorio dentro de otro repositorio, entonce solo lo que hice fue cloner el repositorio fuera del proyecto y solo pasar los scripts php a la carpeta lang y me dejo hacer el commit

Técnicamente poner !lang/*  establecería que los contenidos de lang no deben ser ignorados, por lo que esa regla no haría daño
